# ng serve erroring after NPM 5.0.1 update: Invalid Version:

Tags: angular, npm

I just updated to NPM 5.0.1 and right away I had compilation errors in my Angular 4.1.3 project. After deleting and completely reinstalling my node_modules **(all packages up to date)** I get a strange and red colored error when running `ng serve`:

```
Invalid Version: https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/core/-/core-4.1.3.tgz
TypeError: Invalid Version: https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/core/-/core-4.1.3.tgz
    at new SemVer (/Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/semver/semver.js:293:11)
    at new Version (/Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/@angular/cli/upgrade/version.js:23:36)
    at Function.assertAngularVersionIs2_3_1OrHigher (/Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/@angular/cli/upgrade/version.js:80:23)
    at Class.run (/Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:102:27)
    at Class.Command.validateAndRun (/Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:128:15)
    at /Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:92:22
    at tryCatch (/Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:539:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:554:13)
    at /Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:629:16
    at flush (/Users/bracicot/dev/recruitler/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2414:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

I'm kind of stumped as to what could be causing this short of rolling back NPM. There doesnt seem to be anything online about it either.

UPDATE:
NPM added a package-lock.json file. The Invalid Version is coming from there.

UPDATE 2:
After reinstalling the CLI I get 
`Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'` could it be that the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are not in sync?

UPDATE 3:
Special thanks to @Dylanb124
Yes NPM5 is certainly buggy, the first issue was the package-lock file being created with incorrect values... There is a lot to this issue and I have resolved it. My dev partner was able to get NPM 5 working with a fresh NG project. Therefore we matched the working version against our repo until it built properly. The main conflicts were packages that supported node and mongo (hammer.js) and some others that I was able to remove permanently. (some cleanup was due anyways) in the end we were able to get it running. I would recommend waiting as long as possible to upgrade to NPM 5x

Comment: which node version you are using

Comment: All packages up to date `Node 8` `NPM 5.0.1`

Comment: I was able to mitigate this by deleting package-lock.json, it will be autocreated any way. Try changing its name and then diffing it against the newly created one to trace the issue. I just deleted it and now everything works again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

This issue may be entirely unrelated to package versioning. Attempt the following:

1. Delete all subfolders in node_modules.
2. Perform an `npm install` and pay attention to any initial errors or
   warnings, especially those involving issues with
   downloading/installing packages.
3. Manually install the package via `npm install --save <package-name>`
   and rebuild it with `npm rebuild <package-name>`.

At this point, you can attempt to build your Angular package, hopefully resulting in a successful build.

## Details

I've been dealing with same build issues. However, I was able to get the Angular project to build on one machine, but not another. Both machines are using the same version of NPM (5.0.1) and Node (7.10.0).

It seems the error message regarding incorrect version was not at all related to the root cause. Could you try clearing your **node_modules** folder, and performing an `npm install`.

In my case, I saw numerous warnings and errors related to the **node-sass** npm package. It seems the package was attempting to be downloaded from an invalid Github URL, meaning it was never downloaded, and caused numerous build errors.

My particular solution involved manually installing the package it was attempting to download, and then rebuilding that package manually as well (see [node-sass issues 1601](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1601)).

I'm still attempting to find the true root cause, as there is no reason why this should be an issue on one machine, but not another. I'll update this post with any findings. I believe this may be an installation issue, as I installed NPM 5 differently between the two machines.

## Updates

- Uninstalling NodeJs/NPM, re-installing, and upgrading to NPM 5.0.2 did not seem to make a difference.
- Deleting the node_modules folder and re-installed packages on the machine that still built resulted in a successful replication of the issue, and is now no longer building.
- After trying different version of Nodejs, npm, and numerous other packages, I've decided NPM 5 is just too buggy at the moment. I'm rolling back to NPM 4 for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for writing! Yes NPM5 is certainly buggy. There is a lot to this issue and I have resolved it. My dev partner was able to get NPM 5 working with a fresh NG project. Therefore we matched the working version against our repo until it built properly. The main conflicts were packages that supported node and mongo (hammer.js) and some others that I was able to remove permanently. (some cleanup was due anyways) in the end we where able to get it running and NPM support never got back to me but I would recommend waiting as long as possible to upgrade to NPM 5x

Answer (score 16):

What worked for me on npm 5.0.2

1. delete node_modules
2. `rm -f package-lock.json && npm install`

Comment: The first step for this issue. Thanks

Comment: That is the most useful answer! Didn't know that package-lock.json is interrupting the installing process. What exactly is it for?

Answer (score 1):

> run this command. does this help

```
 npm uninstall --save-dev webpack
 rm -R node_modules
 npm install
```

and then try

> ng serve

Comment: I did run that but I'm using the CLI, it's not a raw webpack project. However, after installing webpack it seems to `build` but does not load... perhaps this new issue is code related as I was mid development when I updated NPM...